# Can't login (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I'm making a complete login system. The register part works just fine but if I try to login, I just get a white screen. No errors, no redirects,... The php code does execute since my url  changes to 'login.php'. I tried multiple ways to make a login, but that dind't work either.

Thanks in advance!

```
  <?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: index_afterlogin.html");
    exit;
}

require_once "config.php";

$email = $password = "";
$email_err = $password_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
     if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Please enter e-mail.";
    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    if(empty($email_err) && empty($password_err)){
        $sql = "SELECT userID, email, password FROM users WHERE email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);

            $param_email = $email;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $email, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["userID"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["email"] = $email;                            

                            header("location: index_afterlogin.html");
                        } else{
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    $email_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you got the MySQLi exception mode switched on? [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments/22662582#22662582)

Comment: Do I have to implement that in my config.php where I link the database?

Comment: Yes, that would be probably the best place. Before you make the connection insert that line from the link.

Comment: I've done that, doesn't work..

Comment: It was meant to show you any SQL errors if you have any. If you didn't get any errors in your error log then that means the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { .. }` - And if not, you'll get a "white page".